# Need to parse strings on data from a big linux text file (~20 millions of rows) and convert to csv

Tags: linux, csv, unix, sed, grep

I have a big file (20M of rows) with the following format per row:

```
(5859785,7410375) (5859799,7410377) LAYER_ACT stringofdatathatislateronrow
(58597,74103) (58597,74103) LAYER_ACT2 stringofdatathatislateronrowmillion
```

I need to have a csv output that is:

```
X              Y
5859785      7410375
58597        74103
```

I know "sed" command on unix can be used to grab things but, I cannot get it work to get the right format. Do you have a better solution to get this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `(`, `)` and `,` as input field separator with awk:

```
awk -F '[(),]' 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"; print "X","Y"} {print $2,$3}' file
```

Output:

```
X       Y
5859785 7410375
58597   74103
```

Change output field separator (OFS) to your needs.